# I want to store webview login even after closing android application

Tags: android, android-webview

I am creating an android app with multiple activities. First ther is activity sign in via web-view and then other activities are  also loading the website from the same url. Problem is I want to keep user logged in even after closing android app.
 So how to do it ?

Comment: Use SharedPreferences. Simple and useful. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: Even if I use shared prefrences but what about cookies ? How to keeped user logged in after starting application again ? Any sample code for webview and sharedprfrences ? ** I want to preserve cookies in webview even after closing app **